# Instantiated object does not have desired scale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get two blocks to respawn vertically with a gap in-between. I have done this however, when I click play, one of the blocks width is too short. this results in having two gaps. how can I stop this from happening. I would only like the one gap which is between the two blocks. the code I am currently using:

```
public Transform block;
public Transform player;
private float objectSpawnedTo = 5.0f;
public static float distanceBetweenObjects = 9.5f;
private float nextCheck = 0.0f;
private ArrayList objects = new ArrayList();
void Start () {
    maintenance(0.0f);
}


void Update () {
    float playerX = player.position.y;
    if(playerX > nextCheck)
    {
        maintenance(playerX);
    }
}

private void maintenance(float playerX)
{
    nextCheck = playerX + 30;
    for (int i = objects.Count-1; i >= 0; i--) 
    {
        Transform blck = (Transform)objects[i];
        if(blck.position.y < (transform.position.y - 30))
        {
            Destroy(blck.gameObject);
            objects.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
    spawnObjects(5);
}

private void spawnObjects(int howMany)
{
    float spawnX = objectSpawnedTo;
    for(int i = 0; i<howMany; i++)
    {
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(6.0f, spawnX, 0);
        float firstRandom = Random.Range(1,8.6f);
        Transform blck = (Transform)Instantiate(block, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        blck.localScale+=new Vector3(firstRandom*2,0,0);
        objects.Add(blck);
        pos = new Vector3(-6.0f, spawnX, 0);
        blck = (Transform)Instantiate(block, pos, Quaternion.identity);
        blck.localScale +=new Vector3((8.6f-firstRandom)*2,0,0);
        objects.Add(blck);
        spawnX = spawnX + distanceBetweenObjects;
    }
    objectSpawnedTo = spawnX;
}
```

i have attached an image to show what i am trying to achieve. the red outline is the mobile screen. also i would like to be able to move the blocks either left or right using touch. how would i go about doing this.

[image]

Comment: You are setting the width to a random number.... `blck.localScale+=new Vector3(firstRandom*2,0,0);` Please be more clear what it is you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: please check amended version of question

Comment: Attached image helps describe what you *want* to happen but not what the *current result is,* i.e. what's wrong?